# Could someone provide the list of similar annotations as of hibernate to be used for database models with reactive client?

Tags: mysql, reactive, quarkus

Could someone provide the list of similar annotations as of hibernate to be used for database models with reactive client? for example, join, id etc. etc.

```
public class Country {
     int id; // Autogenerated incremental unique ID
     String name;
     List<City> cities; //List of cities where country has many cities under it

}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no solution at the moment for a Hibernate for reactive. But work on a Hibernate Reactive solution offering the JPA annotations is ongoing. https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-rx/